# Please enable cookies message (httpwebrequest)

Tags: vb.net, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I'm trying to send a request to a website but it keeps telling me my cookies are not enabled. (But i did used a cookiecontainer in my code)

Here is the code :

```
Private Function does_it_asks_for_cookies() As Boolean
    Dim url As String = "https://www.myhabit.com/?hash="
    Dim req As Net.HttpWebRequest = Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(URL)
    req.CookieContainer = New CookieContainer
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    Dim res As Net.HttpWebResponse = req.GetResponse()
    Dim strm As New IO.StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream())
    Dim html As String = strm.ReadToEnd()
    strm.Dispose()
    res.Dispose()

    If html.Contains("To continue shopping at Amazon.com, please enable cookies in") Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

Usage : MsgBox(does_it_asks_for_cookies)

Comment: Cookies could be shut off in the browser that you are testing on.

Comment: @Chuck the code sample bypasses any browser

Answer (score 0):

While you have a `CookieContainer` the code in your example doesn't actually put anything in it. `HttpWebRequest` doesn't know anything about previous requests and certainly doesn't magically store the contents of any cookies in your container, you will have to do that yourself. Having a `CookieContainer` isn't enough. Most (especially e-commerce) websites are very specific in what they expect there to be present in the form of a cookie, often reporting that cookies aren't turned on when the cookie doesn't contain the proper values. You will have to inspect the web site in a browser to figure out what cookies are set and what values they contain. Google "inspect cookies" to learn how to view cookies in the browser of your choice.